# How to ensure that daylight savings is propogated through all Exchange calendar entries

Tags: exchange-2003, time

In our company, each time that daylight savings time starts or stops, we have calendar entries that fall out of sync by an hour (I cant recall whether they were an hour earlier or later when we switched last spring).  We are using Exchange 2003 and all workstations are using Outlook 2007.

There are no issues with the date of the switch from/to DST, it reliably happens on the right day.

This does not affect all calendar entries, only certain calendar entries, and we have not been able to isolate the problem to a workstation or group.

Besides making sure that all updates have been applied to each client, is there anything else that we can do to make the transition to standard time go smoothly.

Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good points joeqwerty. You might also check that the calendar entries with the problem haven't been made by outside parties who haven't applied the DST patches.

Have you had a look at the [Microsoft Daylight Saving Time Help and Support Center](http://support.microsoft.com/gp/cp_dst)? There are some good links to resources there.

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify: all the workstations and the Exchange server have the applicable DST updates right? Also, have you verified that the affected workstations have the correct time zone set? Are any of these users Blackberry or Goodlink users? If so, have you verified that the handhelds have the appropriate DST patches?